# The number of distinct fractions less than 1

Tags: java, algorithm, time, dynamic-programming

Given a number `N`, it is asked to find the number of distinct fractions such that if the reduced fraction is P/Q (P and Q are co-prime), then P and Q must be `<=N`.
So first I came up with this naive approach.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    // your code goes here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();//number of test cases
    while(t-->0){
        int n = sc.nextInt();//integer N
        int count=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<i;j++){
                if(gcd(i,j)==1)
                    count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
  }
  public static int gcd(int a,int b){
      if(b!=0)
          return gcd(b,a%b);
      else
          return a;
  }
```

Which was rejected as TLE. Then I thought of pre-calculating the values as it was mentioned `N<=1000000`. So I tried this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    // your code goes here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int[] arr = new int[1000001];
    arr[0]=0;
    for(int i=1;i<1000001;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=arr[i-1];
        for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
            if(gcd(i,j)==1)
                arr[i]++;
        }
    }
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    while(t-->0){
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(arr[n]);
    }
  }
  public static int gcd(int a,int b){
      if(b!=0)
          return gcd(b,a%b);
      else
          return a;
  }
```

But now it is showing TLE even for `N=1`,`2` and `3` too. I am not able to understand what is going wrong even if the loops seem correct. Any better approach is also welcome.
NOTE: TLE IS TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED

Comment: What does TLE mean? Too Little Effort?

Comment: You might want to look up Farey sequence, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence

Comment: @subrunner TLE is Time Limit Exceeded

Comment: Second approach in general is worst than first one. First fails for specific large number but second one tries to do even more work computing all possible large numbers. Looks like this problem should have some mathematic trick that will reduce computations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loops are fine. I'm pretty sure something is going wrong in the while loop, i.e. your condition always evaluates to true. It may have something to do with -> meaning imply instead of (t--)>, which I am sure is what you want.

A much better approach is to implement something like the [Farey Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) or the [Stern-Brocot Sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpwUVExX27E).

Comment: I have been using `while(t-->0)` for a long time. It has never caused errors like this before. :(

Comment: And adding to that, the previous solution ran without TLE for `N=1`, `2` and `3` which also has `t-->0`

Comment: In your original program, it might just be that the time complexity of a nested for loop is O(n^2), and you are putting 1000000 in for n. In the second program, it has something to do with the while loop. Can you watch some version of the program running then see where it is getting stuck? It appears that t-->0 is fine. Sorry about that.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FareySequence.html I found this link where it was mentioned N(n)=3*n*n/PI*PI, where PI is 3.14... So I wrote this https://ideone.com/RbGgHW which gives the expected results for `1`,`2` and `3`, but it was judged as wrong answer by the online judge. Can you suggest me anything better?

Comment: That is an asymptotic limit, which basically means it's only an approximation for very large n. Here are some good sources for algorithms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hlvhQZIOQw

Comment: Nothing wrong with the *slide operator* `-->`, although it's fallen out of favour with the youngsters.

Comment: @yobro97 I added another sequence called the Stern-Brocot Sequence that may work better for you in my answer.

Comment: https://ideone.com/82npGs I run this program to check where the fault is. But this indicates there is no fault in the while loop!.....it is TimeLimitExceeded even without while loop

Comment: @AlgorithmsX cool bro...I think this is it!...the Ster-Brocot sequence https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpwUVExX27E

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Euler's totient function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html) and dynamic programming.

*Step 1*: Generate all primes up to the max possible value of n.

*Step 2*: Calculate `totient[i]` for all `1 <= i <= max possible value of n`. Use dynamic programming for this.

- `totient[1] = 0`
- `totient[i] = i - 1` if `i` is prime
- `totient[i] = totient[i/d] * totient[d]` for any `d` that divides `i` (loop over primes to find a `d`)

*Step 3*. The number of irreducible fractions `p/q` with `p < q <= i` is `totient[2] + totient[3] + totient[4] + ... + totient[i]` ([Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) length). Also calculate while calculating totients.

- `numberOfFractions[1] = 0`
- `numberOfFractions[i] = numberOfFractions[i-1] + totient[i]`